# Find error PHP returns to AJAX in JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

this works:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'register.php',
            data: {captcha: captcha
            },

            success: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#success').fadeIn();
            } 
            error: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#captcha').fadeIn();
            $('#catErrorB').fadeIn();
            } 

});
```

sends captcha response to PHP and  if entered correctly, you can register. problem is, is that if you incorectly enter your captcha, the JQuery still runs the functions for a successful run although the PHP ran a "die" and did nothing.

In PHP, if the captcha is entered incorrectly is does this

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
           die ("false");
  } 

  else 

  {
  register
  }
```

How do I request the error that PHP spits out so I can do something like?

```
    success: function(find error) {
        if(error == "false")
        {
        $('#loading').hide();
    $('#captcha').fadeIn();
    $('#catErrorB').fadeIn();
        }
        else
        {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#success').fadeIn();
        }
        }
```

EDIT!:
With your help heres what it looks like now and it works fantastic!!

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'register.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                challenge: challenge,
                response: response,
                zip: zip
            },

            success: function(result) {  
            if (!result.success) { 
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#captcha').fadeIn();
            $('#catErrorB').fadeIn();
            } 
            else { 
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#success').fadeIn();
    } 
} 




});
```

and the PHP

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    $response = array(success => false); 
    echo json_encode($response); 

  } 

  else 
  {

$response = array(success => true); 
echo json_encode($response);
```

Ya'll are the coolest. My first JQuery I've ever done, It's came out so awesome. This site rules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    $response = array(success => false);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else { 
    $response = array(success => true);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

jQuery:

```
success: function(result) { 
    if (!result.success) {
        // Wrong input submitted ..
    }
    else {
        // Correct input submitted ..
    }
}
```

Comment: he also needs to tell $.ajax to return json right now it doesn't

Comment: Can I do that by simply doing this? $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
  url: 'register.php',
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {captcha: captcha},

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use success/failure. Even if the script dies it is still going to return a 200 SUCCESS to your ajax call.

Use JSON to return responses depending on whether or not it is a success and parse and proceed with correct logic

```
<?php

if ( $resp->is_valid ) {
  echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'true' ) );
} else {
  echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'false' ) );
}

?>
```

Then you can parse the response in your AJAX call. Remember, if you call `die('false');` that is still going to return a success message to your ajax function.

Comment: As someone pointed out, you will need to tell your ajax call that it is json, or conversely, use a JS parser like json2.js to parse the response.

Comment: I'm kind of new to JQuery, AJAX & Javascript. Haven't heard of JSON before. Reading through it on the JQuery website. 

.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

Looks like I would use those.

Comment: JSON: Javascript Object Notation - a more modern and accepted approach for ajax and other object-ifying methods of data structures. (Better than XML, the predecessor). The error function is triggered if you were to get an unexpected error in the Ajax channel - such as a 404, 500 error and so forth.

Comment: "if you call die('false'); that is still going to return a success message to your ajax function." That's why I was trying to trick it into returning a something and using if/else statements to decided what to do with it. This way makes much more sense though. Playing with it now, THANK YOU!